# I recently attached an external HD with eSATA in Windows 7. When I try to enable ReadyBoost, I click Test in the device Properties and nothing happens. Why?

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, esata, readyboost

There is a Test button on the ReadyBoost tab within the device properties which, according to help I've seen online, should test my drive's speed and display the results and whether or not I can use ReadyBoost.

Well when I click Test, the button disappears, but absolutely nothing happens. No other information, no errors - I can simply click OK to close the window and that's about it. Are eSATA drives not meant to run ReadyBoost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this microsoft page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-NZ/windows7/products/features/readyboost) they only mention flash devices. I presume because flash storage is so much faster than a hard drive for access times. Having another hard drive is like making your swap file larger, no real speed increase.

Ak